# Firebase Name: com.firebase.core Reason: Configuration fails. It may be caused by an invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Making a call to Firebase.Core.App.Configure() as instructed in the getting started with firebase instruction set at https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseioscloudmessaging
results in error noted below. I have seen other answers to this but they seem to pertain specifically to cordova and the GoogleServices-Info.plist either being corrupted or not copied to a particular folder.

**Error**

> Name: com.firebase.core Reason: Configuration fails. It may be caused
>   by an invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist or set in the
>   customized options.

[image: Nuget]

**Error occurs calling Firebase.Core.App.Configure();**

```cs
 private void RegisterForPushNotifications()
    {

        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {
            // iOS 10
            var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(granted);
            });

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;
        }
        else
        {
            // iOS 9 <=
            var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
            var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
        }

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

        // Firebase component initialize
        Firebase.Core.App.Configure();


        Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.Notifications.ObserveTokenRefresh((sender, e) =>
        {
            var newToken = Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;

            // if you want to send notification per user, use this token
           //TODO need WS calls to store this token in the user table

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newToken);

            connectFCM();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There truly was a GOOGLE_APP_ID field missing from the configuration provided when downloading the GoogleService-Info.plist from the firebase console. After looking at an example found here

https://github.com/HabibAli/FCM-Xamarin-Forms/blob/master/FCM/FCM/FCM.iOS/GoogleService-Info.plist

I added missing properties and the Firebase.Core.App.Configure() call works fine.